SetAttributes on second set of arguments
I am applying functions with the postfix operator syntax (expr//function), and sometimes I add in my definitions some configuration argument (expr//functionWith[2]). Is it possible to SetAttributes[functionWith, HoldAll] and have it hold the expr unevaluated?
Here a dummy example that also wishes Listable as an attribute (although the workaround for that is easier)
ClearAll[inflatedDebt]
SetAttributes[inflatedDebt, {HoldAll, Listable}]
inflatedDebt[names_] := Print[ToString[Unevaluated[names]], " owes now ", 1.2*names];

ClearAll[inflatedDebtBy]
SetAttributesOnSecondSetOfArguments[inflatedDebtBy, {HoldAll, Listable}]
inflatedDebtBy[inflation_][names_] := Print[ToString[Unevaluated[names]], " owes now ", inflation*names];

Alice = 10; Bob = 7;
{Alice, Bob} // inflatedDebt
{Alice, Bob} // inflatedDebtBy[1.5]

The first call gives
(*Alice owes now 12.*)
(*Bob owes now 8.4*)

The second call should give
(*Alice owes now 15.*)
(*Bob owes now 10.5*)


I don't know of a way to get attributes to sort of cascade down so they work for SubValues. You could define an intermediate function, but that would probably be a pain if you do this frequently with different parameters.

You could do it with a pure function, which accepts attributes: ClearAll[inflatedDebtBy]; inflatedDebtBy[inflation_] := Function[{names}, Print[ToString[Unevaluated[names]], " owes now ", inflation*names], {HoldAll, Listable}];

You can't assign attributes to the subvalues of a symbol. You could do what @Domen shows. I learned that here, from some other Q&A.
